# javascript alert firing on document ready even though it's in click event

Tags: javascript

I've got a simple question, the code below keeps firing the alert when the page loads, but the alert is in a click event so I don't know why. Any ideas?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        var blah = document.getElementById('btnChangeScreenSize');
        var blah2 = $('#btnChangeScreenSize');

        $('#btnChangeScreenSize').click(alert(1));
    }
);
</script>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write it like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        var blah = document.getElementById('btnChangeScreenSize');
        var blah2 = $('#btnChangeScreenSize');

        $('#btnChangeScreenSize').click(function() { alert(1) });
    }
);
```

The thing is, when you write: `$('#btnChangeScreenSize').click(alert(1))` the function `alert()` is being called and returns `undefined`. Then you're setting `undefined` as a callback function, which doesn't make sense

Comment: I'll accept your answer here when it lets me in a few minutes, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have this code:

```
$('#btnChangeScreenSize').click(alert(1));
```

That attempts to set `alert(1)` as the click handler (see [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/click/)), but `alert(1)` is evaluated immediately. Instead, you need a callback function, like this:

```
$('#btnChangeScreenSize').click(
    function () {
        alert(1)
    }
);
```